# Python - The global variable is not changing

Tags: python, function, global-variables, global

This is prototype of a code, I am working on. I want to access the global variable in the function 'i()', but i am not able to access it. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
a = 1

### Uses global because there is no local 'a' 
def f(q): 
    global a
    a = q

def g(q):     
    global a 
    a = q

def h(q):     
    global a 
    a = q

def i(func):
    for j in func:
        j
        global a
        print(a)

### Global scope 
print('global : ',a)
q=1
b = f(q)
q=2
c = g(q)
q=3
d = h(q)
func = [b, c, d]
print(func)
i(func)
print('global : ',a)
```

## **Output**

```
global :  1
[None, None, None]
3
3
3
global :  3
```

Comment: You are accessing the global variable just fine. Note, you probably meant to *call* the functions you are iterating over, so `j()` instead of `j`. More importantly, you **shouldn't be using mutable global state to begin with**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga except that the contents of the list passed to `i` are not the functions themselves, they're the return values from calls to those functions.

Comment: @MarkRansom ah yes, good point. Read this too fast...

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do.  The output you show is exactly what I'd expect from the code you've given.

Comment: @MarkRansom the global variable is not changing function by function. I want the global variable changing as the function changes

Comment: You're not printing the global variable after every function call, so how would you know if it's changing?

Answer (score 0):

```
b = f(q)
```

`f(q)` calls the function. `b` is the return value of the function, in this case `None`. Later on, just `j` by itself on a line does absolutely nothing. You need to do `j()` there to call the function there. And pass the function itself, `f`, not `f()`. You can’t store “a function call” in a list and pass it around. The function gets called when you attach the `()`, what comes out of that is only its return value.

For simplicities sake go back to your original code in which you called `f()` without `q`; how to pass a function and arguments to it around is another step further.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the suggestion. But I think it's not working for me. I tried what you told, "1. I put parentheses after the `j` ; 2. pass the `f` inside `j()`. But unfortunately it is giving me an error for it"